# How to handle keyboard event in fighting game development?

Tags: game-engine

I'm try to develop a fighting game which involving detecting key pressing and combination.

However, things are more complicated than I thought, following are some main point:

1)When user press A twice quickly, the role should run.

2)When user press some keys, say A + L + D, the role should cast.

3)When role's cast is over, if arrow key is pressed, the role should move left or right, otherwise it should standby.

4)When role is jumping, it can not move(meaning left\right arrow key press is ignored), but can attack.

5)Key combination requiring short interval time and/or order.

and so on...

I have thought about several methods, but can not solve the problem perfectly.

Things go totally a mass.

Can anyone provide me some good algorithms or methods to handle such problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need a [Finite State Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) to represent and build up your combination states. Your input/keypress system or relevant layer will need to support features like:

- Buffered input (so your input events are queued up and aren't just sampling immediately this frame, especially important in fighting games where the cost of missing inputs is very noticeable)
- Counting multiple presses
- Timing since last press (globally, and locally for same key), and timing of held press.
- perhaps keeping a reliable buffer of last `n` key actions.

Your finite state machine would have intermediate states for each succession of the combo, with a wrong input cancelling and resetting the state. A lot of the FSM state change conditions will be based on a combination of timers and input. However, FSM will help greatly with animation and tracking state/movement generally, not just for input.